# Getting error 401 when having a api request for here api

Tags: here-api

When I try to make a request from here api I realized that on Saturday I was not able to make them anymore. When I looked at the response I was getting an error:
"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"Sentry-EUM Error. EUM returned HTTP response code of 401 "httpStatus":401,"errorCode":401311,"message":"Requesting client status is not active.","error":"invalid_request","error_description":"errorCode: '401311'. Requesting client status is not active."}. The Sentry cache was therefore not updated.

I don't know why I am getting this error and could not find anything related to it.

Comment: I would need more information to investigate further, please provide your AppID and let us know which API/Services are you trying to use. Thanks

Comment: We are still waiting for the response. Otherwise we will close this case.

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same issue. API call: https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?apiKey=<apikey>&limit=100&at=10.376459,123.843356&in=bbox:123.921855,10.402198,123.974179,10.453671&categories=700-7450